# Time period of Azwars

Tags: alwar, azwar

The traditional schools of south Indian vaishnavism place Azwars around the beginning of Kali Yuga. That raises a bunch of questions and thoughts in my mind -

1. Do the language constructs (Tamil) used by The Azwars align with the early Tamil literature (of Sangam period or prior)?
2. Some accounts ([like wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathamuni)) suggest that Sri Nathamuni lived during the same time as Sri Nammazhwar did. It also seems like Sri Madurakavi Azwar was born before Sri Nammazwar. Looks like all the three saints had overlapping time period. But Azwars like Sri Kulasekhara Azwar lived latter and much after Nathamuni. If all these are true, how could Sri Nathamuni have compiled the Divya Prabhandam including the works of Sri Kulasekhara Azwar and Sri Thirumangai Azwar, when they lived at a much later time period (and after the period of Sri Nathamuni)
3. A shorter / condensed form of those two questions is - can someone point me to any research studies in this regard? Broadly speaking, the time and works of the Azwars. I am looking for something like a critical edition that provides a research perspective.

I do understand that often the religious accounts differ from the historical ones, or conclusions based on a critical study. While I respect the religious views, and appreciate faith oriented answers to this question, what I am really seeking is something like a critical edition, or a research study or a published paper on this subject.